# A good and polite way to ask "How long have you been playing drums?"

Tags: grammar, translation, politeness, questions

How to correctly ask "how long have you been playing drums?" in a forum?
I tried to come up with my own question but I don't know if it is grammatically correct and/or polite. Here is what I came up with

> 貴方ドラム叩いているますどのくらいの時間か？

Could you please help me with this?

Comment: You seem to have problems conjugating words: could you double check 叩くている and いるます? Also, do you know about です as politeness marker?

Comment: well I know that 叩くis to play drums and and I tried used て-いる-form to indicate an action that is ongoing and also ます to show politeness

Comment: Yes, I figured. Please take a look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Japanese_verb_conjugations#te_form and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Japanese_verb_conjugations#Summary_of_verb_conjugations (same page) for how to conjugate verbs. Your attempt is actually pretty good. I imagine the grammar points you're missing are covered in the first few chapters of a basic textbook, which I would recommend you to consult first.

Comment: Yes thank you @Earthliŋ, I found a few mistakes. but also you sugested using です and I cant quite comprehend where to put it.

Comment: By "drums" are you referring to [ドラム](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/7/77/Drumkit.jpg/300px-Drumkit.jpg) or [太鼓](http://www.azcom.ne.jp/images/product_photos/gakki/wadaiko01.jpg)?

Comment: I'm referring to a western stile drum set

Comment: I see. I would say ドラムを始めてどのくらいになりますか？

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are on the right track, but as someone has commented your conjugations need some work.

However, I'll give you what I would suggest is a natural way to ask this.

```
ドラムを叩き始めてどれくらいになりますか？
```

I think you could replace 叩き始めて with simply 叩いて, but I think the above is more clear.

Besides your issues with です and ます, you don't need to use 貴方. Often in Japanese it's best not to use any word for "you", as it is implied and each word that means "you" has its own nuance.

If you want to use this for other things, you can just put the action in the "pre-masu" form (i.e. 食べ) followed by this phrase:

```
〜始めてどれくらいになりますか？
```

This would translate to "How long have you been ~?"

EDIT: Replaced 〜ですか with になりますか

EDIT: Added general pattern

Comment: Oh ok I had this impresion that to imply something it was suposed to be a live conversation. I gues Im realy green at this. And allso could you explain where in your example time referance is, or it is implied too.

Comment: sorry if Im too insistent I just want to squeeze every bit of information that  can

Comment: Would be much more natural if you used 「なる」 at the end.

Comment: @l'électeur: Thanks. I knew that was possible but didn't realize it was that much better. Will fix it.

Comment: @GoldeEggs: Yes, this line can be used in a live conversation. I'm not sure what you mean by "time reference". The phrase literally means "how much (time) will it be (since) beginning to play the drums", where the part in parenthesis is implied.

Comment: What I ment to ask is what part in that sentence is refering to time.  In english sentence it woud be "how long" part. I get it that its not the same in japanese. I wondered if this form of sentence could be reusable in other cases like asking "how long have you been playing tennis?" or something like that . for that i want to fully understand this sentence. It realy looks complicated from my perspective

Comment: "どれくらい” is "how long" or "how much" and "なる" is the verb for "to become", which here translates to something like "would be...". I added a general form of this pattern in my post, check that out.

Comment: @l'électeur: Do you think "~叩いて" is as natural as "〜叩き始めて"?